# Calendars not working after npm run build

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm using vue2-datepicker for a calendar. in development when i click on the input box in my form it works perfectly fine with the calendar appearing above. however when i do `npm run build` and load up the resulting page, when i do the same nothing happens, no calendar appearing above and more so no error in the developer console of the browser.

i have tried running the code in another browser and there was no change. i tried another calendar and i got the exact same behaviour where in dev it works but after building it doesn't.

this is my package.json (redacting company information)

```
{
  "name": "[REDACTED]",
  "authors": [
    "[REDACTED]"
  ],
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "serve build -p 3080",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "test": "start-server-and-test start http-get://localhost:3080 cy:run",
    "styleguide": "vue-styleguidist server",
    "styleguide:build": "vue-styleguidist build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.7",
    "[REDACTED]": "[REDACTED]",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "serve": "^13.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.7",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@cypress/vue": "^2.2.3",
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.15",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "cypress": "^9.4.1",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "vue-breakpoints": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-styleguidist": "^4.44.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^3.10.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require("prerender-spa-plugin");
const Renderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer;
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");

const routes = [[REDACTED]];

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "build.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]?[hash]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["vue-style-loader", "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.js$/,
      //   use: [
      //     {
      //       loader: "file-loader",
      //       options: {
      //         name: "[name].[ext]",
      //         outputPath: "js/",
      //       },
      //     },
      //   ],
      // },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: "vue/dist/vue.esm.js",
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: false,
    open: "chrome",
  },
  devtool: "#eval-source-map",
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()],
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  module.exports.devtool = "#source-map";
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"',
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "PRODUCTION prerender-spa-plugin",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/index.html"),
      favicon: path.join(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico"),
    }),
    new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
      staticDir: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
      routes: routes,
      renderer: new Renderer({
        headless: false,
        renderAfterDocumentEvent: "render-event",
      }),
    }),
  ]);
} else {
  // NODE_ENV === 'development'
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "DEVELOPMENT prerender-spa-plugin",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      filename: path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"),
      favicon: path.join(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico"),
    }),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you _"loading up the resulting page"_?

Comment: @Phil i open the page in localhost:3080, eg if the path is /my-account/dob when i open to localhost:3080/my-account/dob. also no idea about Vue CLI, the instructions i have is that i use `npm run build` to build and send the index.html pages that are created but i can test the build out in localhost:3080

Comment: So you run `npm run build`. Are you then running `npm start` to start serving files?

Comment: @phil yes. i go so far as to stop running `npm start` when i make a change and start it up again after i finish building

Answer (score 0):

The [serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve) utility isn't configured by default to support HTML5 history mode. The solution to this is to run `serve` in *single mode* to...

> Rewrite all not-found requests to `index.html`

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "serve -s -p 3080 build"
}
```

The alternative is to just open the default page (ie `http://localhost:3080/`) and navigate to where you want to go.

Comment: when you save *"navigate to where you want to go"* do you mean typing in the url after going to the default page or using a hyperlinks?

Comment: Using hyperlinks, presuming you have any. Just run `serve` in single mode, it should work just fine

Comment: no luck. when i change command to what you have and restart it it's just stuck on the main page and none of the other links work. also the page with this calendar is on a "my account" section which can't be navigated to without logging in which is impossible as there is no backend code. to validate the credentials. i did however add add a link on the default page directly to it to see if it made any difference but it still didn't work both before or after i updated the start command